# Can I share the code JUST with my client in BSD License?

Tags: licensing, bsd

I am wondering if I can use a license like BSD in the code of a software I am making for a client.

They are not a software company so I don't think they want an exclusive use, but I want to give them the code and they can modify it, share it or use other company to continue developing it.

However I don't want to be limited to use the code or selling the software to another company, or create a new version. Do I need to publish the code online for every body who wants to see it or download it? Or I just need to share it with my client in a private context?

Comment: In your agreement, who will hold the copyright to the software? Often when you do work as part of your job, copyright goes to them by default ("work for hire").

Answer (score 2):

If a client has hired you to create software for them, it is not a given that you own the copyrights on that software. Check your contract what is states about copyrights (or the broader term of intellectual property rights) and if the contract is silent about it, check your local laws.

If you don't have the copyrights, you don't have the right to say what license terms would apply to the software and you also don't have the right to use/sell the code to another client.

If you do have the copyrights, then you can determine under which conditions the client can use the software and if they get the right to make changes to it. You then also have the right to use the software for other clients and you can provide it to those clients under different conditions.

In no case are you required to publish the software to the general public.

Comment: Actually we are in the process to create the proposal/contract for the project, so we want to be clear